# Map<String, Long> to Map<String, Boolean> if long is > X with Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am looking for a Stream Function to get a Map<String, Boolean> from Map<String, Long>. if the Long is greater than value X, it should be true, otherwise false. Long acts as counter in this case.

Without stream, I figured out this works:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cars = {"Audi A4", "VW Golf", "Nissan GTR", "Audi A4", "Mercedes Benz C63 AMG", "Skoda Octavia", "Mercedes Benz C63 AMG", "Nissan GTR", "VW Polo", "Nissan GTR"};
    
    // count the occurences of a string in the array to a map
    Map<String, Long> carsOccurences = Stream.of(cars).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    
    Map<String, Boolean> moreThanTwoCars = new HashMap<>();
    
    //if a string occures more than 1 time, put true else put false
    for(Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : carsOccurences.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue() > 1)
        moreThanTwoCars.put(entry.getKey(), true);
        else
        moreThanTwoCars.put(entry.getKey(), false);
    }
```

Is there any way to do the for-loop with a Stream? Maybe even without the Map<String, Integer> but directly from the String-Array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `if else` can be replaced by just `moreThanTwoCars.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() > 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stream, but it won't be much cleaner. I'd just simplify the loop a little:

```
carsOccurences.forEach((key, value) -> moreThanTwoCars.put(key, value > 1));
```

Alternatively, if you have Guava you can use `Maps.transformValues()`:

```
Map<String, Boolean> moreThanTwoCars = Maps.transformValues(carsOccurences, v -> v > 1);
```

Note that the latter doesn't reconstruct the full map. It's just a view that delegates to the original map and converts values on the fly. But you can always pass it into a `new HashMap<>(...)` if you need them separated.

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't a better approach than

```
Map<String, Long> carsOccurences = Stream.of(cars).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
  Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
Map<String, Boolean> carsMoreThanTwo = carsOccurrences.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
       Entry::getKey,
       entry -> entry.getValue() > 1));
```

Comment: [There is a better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76234866/2711488). The question is a variation of the xy problem, but less problematic as the actual goal still is recognizable…

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to count the identical cars when you only want to know whether there’s more than one. You can collect the intended map in the first place:

```java
Map<String, Boolean> moreThanTwoCars = Stream.of(cars).collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), car -> false, (car1, car2) -> true));
```

This utilizes the fact that the `valueMapper` function is evaluated when a key is encountered the first time and the `mergeFunction` is evaluated when encountering a key more than once.